# Can not associate file types on safari with iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, safari

I'm making an sample application which can read and share many kind of files,included docs, videos, audios, images,... One of most important its feature is associate with mail attaches and Safari. In fact, I did open successfully docs in mail attaches following the tutorial in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application/2781290#2781290) but it was not working on Safari. I tried an another application which can open document file and it works perfectly on Safari.

This is a part of my plist file:

```
    UIFileSharingEnabled
        
        CFBundleDocumentTypes
        
            
                CFBundleTypeIconFiles
                
                    officedocs-icon50.png
                    officedocs-icon144.png
                
                CFBundleTypeName
                Office Documents Pro
                LSHandlerRank
                Owner
                CFBundleTypeRole
                Viewer
                LSItemContentTypes
                
                    public.plain-text
                    public.utf8-plain-text 
                    com.apple.traditional-mac-​plain-text
                    public.rtf
                    com.apple.quicktime-movie (kUTTypeQuickTimeMovie)
                    public.xml
                    public.audio
                    public.movie
                    public.tiff
                    public.image
                    com.microsoft.word.doc
                    com.microsoft.word.docx
                    com.microsoft.excel.xls
                    com.microsoft.excel.xlsx
                    com.adobe.pdf
                    com.microsoft.powerpoint.​ppt
                    com.microsoft.powerpoint.​pptx
                    public.presentation
                    com.apple.keynote.key
```